# Reading web.config values in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, web-config

I have inherited a legacy classic asp site that I need to support, and am in the process of setting up a dev/debugging environment so I don't have to work on the production server.

The code is a bit of a mess, and there are literaly hundreds of connection strings dotted around the place in various .asp files.  These all contain hard-coded references to the SQL server, etc.

I really don't want to have to replace all of these with my local dev environment SQL DB settings, so I was wondering if there was an easy way to get classic asp to read from a .net web.config file.  This way I could change all of the hard-coded connection strings to read from this one place, and then I only need to define the server details in one place.

This would mean that I could then write code & debug locally, and all I would have to do is change a couple of values in the web.config before deployment.

Please provide clear examples in your answer, as I'm new to classic asp & I'm really not liking it at this stage.  Can't wait to redevelop it all in .net ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a server-side-include with all the app settings you need. It will be much easier (and faster) to implement than reading a web.config and give you the same flexibility.

**config.asp**

```
<%
Dim connectionString
connectionString = "your connectionstring here"
%>
```

**Default.asp**

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<!-- #include virtual="config.asp" -->
<%
'---
' ... use connectionString here
'---
%>
```

From what you tell you could improve the rest of your heritage using SSI in other places too.

Comment: Thanks, yeah there is loads I could do to improve it, but as far as I am concerned it's dead code.  I want to do as little as possible with it & redevelop it from scratch :)

Comment: @bob:  But use the file extension .asp not .inc.  If the IIS server has a .* mapping you may accidentally make it possible for an external machine to download /config.inc.  If the connection strings can contain usernames and passwords so its not something you want to allow external access to.

Comment: @Anthony Maybe using integrated security for a dedicated Application Pool user would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 26):

The usual place to do this in classic ASP is in an application variable in the global.asa file:

```
SUB Application_OnStart
    application("connectionstring")= "[your connectionstring]"
END SUB
```

You can then use `application("connectionstring")` on every page without having to have an include on the page.

Comment: +1 Clean code, easy to use. Refer for [this](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_globalasa.asp) page to know more about global.asa file

Comment: Never thought of that before.. :-o (Great way to do this in 2017) ;)