# Classic ASP centralized Database credentials

Tags: asp-classic

our current web application is built using Classic ASP. Most of the asp pages in the source code has the database username and password hard-coded. Now we are required to make them in centralized and access that function for DB connections.

we are using

```
  db = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
  db.open connectionString, username, password
```

My questions are 
1. Can i use registry's to store and access username and Password (encrypted) in classic ASP ? is it possible without any third part libraries ?
2. can we implement the reading username & password function in a dll and make use of that function in my asp page.
3. is there any other approach to handle this?

Note, not to store the username & password in flat files

Comment: See if http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/dsn.php and http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/dsn_database_connection.php help you out (yes they are for classic asp, ignore the php extension)

Comment: @Jon,Sure will check the links, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can centralise the connection string, just store the credentials in the connectionstring and store the connectionstring in an application variable.

I have answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255685/reading-web-config-values-in-classic-asp/7258302#7258302).

You don't need to open connections using connectionstring, username and password, you can embed the username and password in the connectionstring. Below is an example of a SQL server connection string:

```
connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=YOUR_DATABASE_SERVER; Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE; User ID=YOUR_USERNAME; Password=YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: thank you. My question here is 'connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=YOUR_DATABASE_SERVER; Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE; User ID=YOUR_USERNAME; Password=YOUR_PASSWORD"' the database server name, user id and password still has to be mentioned as a plain text in global.asa / config file etc... which is clearly visible to the person who login to the machine (other than admin account). I am looking for something where DB connection opening are all done in dll and call the function from classic asp code... Is it Possible ?

Comment: It is possible to write a COM DLL in VB6 or a DLL with a COM wrapper in .NET you can call from ASP. In fact at my company we have done so ourselves and that works, however, if you need to change the database or server, you would need to re-compile, so that's not very friendly. You might want to try @Jon P's suggestion, and create a system DSN on your server http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/dsn.php. I'm not sure if you can secure the DSN or the data sources tool, but there would be no credentials in a text-file that way. The username/password is stored in the DSN, and ASP can call the DSN by name.

Comment: i tried the procedure mentioned in [link]webcheatsheet.com/asp/dsn.php. Created a DSN name under SystemDSN for SQL Server. in my classic ASP code, i invoked the same, then i got an error pop-up "0x80040e4d - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. what should i do, as i do not want to hard code password in ASP file.

Comment: Well, that message indicates that your DSN connection is not configured correctly. Have a look here: http://www.stoneedge.com/help/mergedProjects/3rdparty/Creating_ODBC_Connections_in_Microsoft_Windows_7.htm There is also a "test connection..." button you can use to check your DSN connection.